# Unsure why this regex pattern prints out the result it does

Tags: regex, groovy

I am attempting to learn regex and have come across a pattern that i am having trouble with - i am unable to figure how it is works exactly. What is the value of x? The language is Groovy.

```
x=(("World Hotel =~ /^(W....)\s+H(.*)$/)[0][2])
```

I can follow the regex itself but the values in the final 2 square brackets are a mystery to me. The value printed is 'otel', can someone please explain why this is?

Comment: It would help if you specify language. Second bracket is match group index. First probably means first match.

Comment: that looks like a syntax error in ANY language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the regex ends at the `/`. So we have the expression

```
"World Hotel =~ /^(W....)\s+H(.*)$/
```

which matches the string `World Hotel` against the regex `^(W....)\s+H(.*)$`. This will place `World` into the first group, and `otel` into the second capturing group. The first capturing group requires an upper-case `W` at the very start of the string, followed by four arbitrary characters; after that whitespace is matched to an arbitrary non-zero length, followed by an upper-case `H`; the last capturing group then matches the rest of the string until its end.

Having never used Groovy I can only speculate that the index expressions afterwards `[0]` and `[2]` will retrieve the first (and only) match (`[0]`) and the second capturing group of that match (`[2]`), respectively. Which would explain the result you're seeing.

Also you seem to have one closing parenthesis too much.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand what the capturing groups do now, i was thinking about them an incorrect context before hand.